# Having problems with print/file writer

Tags: java

For this assignment I was to write a code that would take a file (Numbers.txt) and calculate the mean and standard deviation of the numbers and print them out to a different file (Results.txt). My code compiled fine but when i go to enter Numbers.txt into my keyboard i get an error message.

Here is a snippet of my code

```
filename = keyboard.nextLine();

File file = new File(filename);          //Create a FileReader object passing it the filename
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);   
line = inputFile.nextLine();             //priming read to read the first line of the file
while (inputFile.hasNextDouble())        //create a loop that continues until you are at the end of the file
{   
sum += inputFile.nextDouble();         //convert the line into a double value and add the value to the sum
    count ++;                          //increment the counter
    inputFile.hasNext();              //read a new line from the file
}
inputFile.close();                     //close the input file
mean = (sum/count);                    //store the calculated mean


File file2 = new File(filename);          //Create a FileReader object passing it the filename
 Scanner inputFile2 = new Scanner(file2);  //reconnect to the FileReader object passing it the    filename
                                        //reconnect to the BufferedReader object passing it the   FileReader object.
sum = 0;                                  //reinitialize the sum of the numbers
count = 0;                                //reinitialize the number of numbers added
line = inputFile2.nextLine();            //priming read to read the first line of the file
while (inputFile2.hasNextDouble())       //loop that continues until you are at the end of the file
{                                
  sum += inputFile2.nextDouble();
inputFile2.nextDouble();
}
 difference = inputFile2.nextDouble() - mean;  //convert the line into a double value and subtract the mean
 sum += Math.pow(difference,2);             //add the square of the difference to the sum
    count ++;                                 //increment the counter
   if (inputFile2.hasNextDouble())
   inputFile2.hasNext();                      //read a new line from the file
   inputFile2.close();                         //close the input file
   stdDev = Math.sqrt(sum/count);             //store the calculated standard deviation
```

and here is the error message i get

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at StatsDemo.main(StatsDemo.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

I'm sure I've made numerous errors with my coding, but i'm not experienced enough yet to notice them. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Finally, got the program to run and calculate the mean, but now I having a little difficulty figuring out how to use the nextDouble in conjunction with the subtraction of the mean. I believe i have to convert the line into a double value. Here's the part i'm having a bit trouble with:

```
File file2 = new File(filename);          //Create a FileReader object passing it the filename
Scanner inputFile2 = new Scanner(file2);  //reconnect to the FileReader object passing it the filename
                                        //reconnect to the BufferedReader object passing it the    FileReader object.
sum = 0;                                  //reinitialize the sum of the numbers
count = 0;                                //reinitialize the number of numbers added
line = inputFile2.nextLine();            //priming read to read the first line of the file
while (inputFile2.hasNextDouble())       //loop that continues until you are at the end of the file
{                                
  sum += inputFile2.nextDouble();

 difference = inputFile2.nextDouble() - mean;  //convert the line into a double value and subtract the mean
 sum += Math.pow(difference,2);             //add the square of the difference to the sum
    count ++; 
}//increment the counter
   if (inputFile2.hasNextDouble())
   {
   inputFile2.hasNext();                      //read a new line from the file
   inputFile2.close();                         //close the input file
   stdDev = Math.sqrt(sum/count);             //store the calculated standard deviation            
   }
```

Comment: Someone else already provided a good answer, but I just wanted to comment that you should learn to read your error messages better. In your error message you see `at StatsDemo.main(StatsDemo.java:47)`. The 47 is the line number where the exception occurs, I think it points to the line `line = inputFile.nextLine();`.

Answer (score 1):

You closed the Scanner::inputFile and then used it again. As you can imagine, you can't use it if you closed it!

Comment: That solved one problem, but I can't seem to get the program to run still.

Comment: @Robert If you do not tell us what the next error is there is no way we can help you. Maybe something also goes wrong with this if-statement: `if (inputFile.hasNextDouble());`? Placing a semicolon directly after an if-statement makes it pretty useless...

Comment: I edited my original post with the new error message for readability.

Comment: The error message is thrown when there is no element to be found. You can see that you are doing inputFile.nextDouble the second time, without checking if it exists. What exactly did you do to fix? If you just removed the closing statement, then you are still reading the first file. I think you mean to read the second file. You need to double check that it is organized in a proper way, so that you don't read from files you don't mean to. If you unsure about the code itself, then let me know and I can try to clarify it for you.

Comment: @RobertSayegh Also if you can please keep the original question as is and then add new error to the bottom, that would be great. Otherwise this answer doesn't make sense :)

Answer (score 0):

After changing line 47 from `line = inputFile.nextLine();` to `line = inputFile2.nextLine();` ([as suggested by user1598503](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26548814/2541501)), you now get a [`NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) on line 53.

It basically says your Scanner has no next double. Which is quite logical, because you have a while loop on line 48 which loops until it reaches the end of the file. Therefore, when you request the next double after the while loop, you are at the end of the file and there is no next double. [The Java docs explain quite clearly why](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble()) the `NoSuchElementException` gets thrown.

You need to change your while-loop. Try to experiment more with it and/or find a good Java tutorial. I'm sure if you spend more time on it that you can make your program work.

Good luck!