# Unsure on converting strings to double

Tags: java

For this program I plan on taking a file (numbers.txt) and finding the mean and standard deviation of the numbers and printing them in another .txt file. I believe the problem I have here involves strings and converting them so I can use them in my equation. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
File file2 = new File(filename);          //Create a FileReader object passing it the filename
Scanner inputFile2 = new Scanner(file2);  //reconnect to the FileReader object passing it the filename
                                          //reconnect to the BufferedReader object passing it the   FileReader object.
sum = 0;                                  //reinitialize the sum of the numbers
count = 0;                                //reinitialize the number of numbers added
line = inputFile2.nextLine();             //priming read to read the first line of the file

while (inputFile2.hasNextDouble())        //loop that continues until you are at the end of the file
{                                
   sum += inputFile2.nextDouble();    
   difference = inputFile2.nextDouble() - mean;  //convert the line into a double value and subtract the mean
   sum += Math.pow(difference,2);                //add the square of the difference to the sum
   count ++;                                     //increment the counter

   if (inputFile2.hasNextDouble())
   {
       inputFile2.hasNext();                     //read a new line from the file
       inputFile2.close();                       //close the input file
       stdDev = Math.sqrt(sum/count);            //store the calculated standard deviation            
   }
}
```

Edit:
Here is the error message I am getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.hasNextDouble(Unknown Source)
at StatsDemo.main(StatsDemo.java:48)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: What is the type for sum and count and what exactly is your question?

Comment: Are these just separated by whitespace or is there some other delimiter?

Comment: You mention that your problem involves strings and converting them, but you didn't tell us what your problem *is*.  What is your program doing? What is it supposed to do? What errors (if any) are you getting? When asking for help with a program that is not running correctly you need to provide a specific problem you are having, the desired behavior and (ideally) an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Read the API doc: hasNextDouble() and hasNext() don't read the next line or the next double. They only tell you if there is a next token or a next double. OTOH, nextDouble() does read the **next** double, every time you call it. So, calling it twice reads two doubles.

Comment: Sum is a double, count is an int, and stdDev is a double. I don't really have a question per say,but when I run the program I don't get a value for my standard deviation, which is what the program is suppose to calculate. I just receive a value of 0, in the same program I am able to calculate the mean of the .txt but not the standard deviation.

Comment: If you don't really have a question *per se*, you shouldn't be posting on StackOverflow.

Comment: The exception is quite clear: you're trying to read from the scanner after you have closed it, and that is not allowed.

Comment: Put a specific question in your post, and you will start getting replies. Simple as that!

Comment: Can you put a data sample in your post?

Comment: The error message says the scanner is closed, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 0):

Well what happens is that you execute one iteration of your while-loop and then close it with `inputFile2.close();`, and after closing, the while-loop checks if it needs to do another iteration with `inputFile2.hasNextDouble()`, but it cannot check if a next double is available because you just closed the scanner!

You can solve your `IllegalStateException` error by either placing a [`break`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) after closing the scanner to get out of the while-loop or moving the line `inputFile2.close();` out of your while-loop.

[As I said before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548778/having-problems-with-print-file-writer#comment41720459_26548778), you should really *learn to read and understand your error messages yourself*. You can see the following in your error message: `at StatsDemo.main(StatsDemo.java:48)`. It tells you to look at line 48 of your program. I suspect `while (inputFile2.hasNextDouble())` is line 48 in your code (you did not tell us in your question, it would be nice if you did though..). Then you should wonder: "why is my scanner closed at this point?". Then you should look where you close your scanner. And you'll see you only close the scanner on line 59: `inputFile2.close();`. So you'll know that line gets executed. Then you should think: "is this the behavior I want? Do I want to close my scanner there?". If yes, then place a *break* so you won't check *hasNextDouble()* again in your while-loop. If no, then move the *close()* to some other point where you actually want it.

If you want to know what lines of your code get executed in which order, you could also [use a debugger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/user.1112/e17455/run_debug_java.htm) (most IDEs have one). Or debug by placing, for example, [`println("test 1")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out), `println("test 2")`, etc. (it sometimes is helpful for quick debugging, but it's better to use a debugger)

And, as others have already said, you should really work on [formatting your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Clearly state your problem, make the problem as specific as possible, show what you understand and what you don't understand and show actual research efforts. The internet is filled with Java tutorials and code examples that explain these simple things that you want to perform, so you could really do your research better.

Also, the title of your question is really misleading. The error you posted in your question has nothing to do with converting a string to a double.

Good luck on learning Java!